# USB-C pulldown on the CC lines: Is one resistor enough?

Tags: usb-c, usb-pd

I want to charge a small, battery-powered device via a USB-C socket. It has a single LiPo battery, so 5V is fine. Since I want to make the connection as simple as possible, I do not want to engage in enumeration. My understanding is that a 5.1 kΩ pulldown on the CC lines will signal the source to behave like a conventional USB charger and supply 5V at 500 mA max. Furthermore, since the connection is reversible, only one CC line should be queried. Now my thinking is that it should be enough to connect both CC lines and to have one single resistor pull down this connection. Or do I need one resistor per line?

Comment: I know it's daunting, but you really should go through the relevant USB-C standard documents. They are freely available and should answer every conceivable question you may have :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Guess where I have my information from ... however, at 373 pages and written as if it should help you fall asleep fast, I was hoping for expert help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both resistors to ground "Rd" are mandatory. See [Spec](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf) at page 151 and around. Figure 4-5 is normative.

One famous example of failed attempt to do this optimization is RaspberryPi 4 which received quite [a lot](https://hackaday.com/2019/07/16/exploring-the-raspberry-pi-4-usb-c-issue-in-depth/) [of](https://techcrunch.com/2019/07/09/the-raspberry-pi-4-doesnt-work-with-all-usb-c-cables/) [press](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/07/raspberry-pi-4-uses-incorrect-usb-c-design-wont-work-with-some-chargers/) coverage about its non-compliant USB Type-C.

In short, don't do this. It will break.

Benson Leung has a [nice writeup](https://medium.com/@leung.benson/how-to-design-a-proper-usb-c-power-sink-hint-not-the-way-raspberry-pi-4-did-it-f470d7a5910) about ins and outs of this.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about the Raspi 4 USB issue! But using a 4.7 kΩ instead of a 5.1 kΩ (E3 instead of E24) is still within spec (±20%). I cannot understand why they pick a harder to get value when a very common value is nearby.

Comment: Beware, if you take a 4.7kΩ resistor, you must take a -13%/+30% or better one (but this is not in E3 any more), as you already ate some margin by taking an off value. 5.1kΩ is easy enough to source, and generally sells for the same price range as 4.7kΩ today.

Comment: Right, I am aware of this. However, it is actually easier to get ±1% resistors than ones with ±10 or 20%. Only capacitors get expensive when you narrow the tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where will you plug your device into, and with what kind of cable.

If you use an active cable, it uses only one wire as CC and the other wire as VConn, so if you have such a cable, the PC can detect which way you have plugged the active cable and which way the PC receptacle CC1 and CC2 pins are used for single CC wire and Vconn wire of the cable.

But then you must plug in the cable into your device in one correct orientation, where the CC wire of the cable connects to resistor on your receptacle. It will not work if that end is flipped, and the cable CC wire sees nothing, and the VConn wire is connected to the 5.1k resistor instead.

Edit: Actually it does not depend on the cable. Cables have only single CC wire between plug CC pins, and the other plug CC pin is used for Vconn so it is not wired between plugs.

So no, one resistor is not enough. A device needs two resistors to work with either connector flip polarity.

Some cheap devices with no flipping support for USB3 wires choose to implement only one flip polarity, and that is not compliant with USB specs so these devices should not be manufactured or  sold. Yet they are bought and used, but at least they were cheap.

Comment: Thank you for your hint to Vconn! To clarify, I was planning to connect the two CC lines and pull down this connection to ground with that single 5.1 kΩ resistor. Vconn is only activated once the connection has been established, and without enumeration, it never should be switched on.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Yes, that would also have been wrong and some devices do this. They only work with passive cables becausr a passive cable leaves thr VConn floating and active cable pulls VConn down, so a single 5k1 resistor would be affected by this.